# Slitting a page into quadrants

Tags: css, viewport

I want to split a webpage into 4 equal quadrants. These quadrants should fill the entire page, and collapse upon window size. The quadrants need to fill the whole viewport of the window.

I can use vh and vw and have it working, but I know it's support is rather flakey.

Ideally, any solution would work with bootstrap.css but not essential.

Many thanks

Comment: Viewport units have ***excellent*** support - http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `width: 50%` and `height: 50%` 4 times and add `left: 50%` and `top: 50%` with `position: absolute;`:

```css
div {
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  background: blue;
}
#or {
  left: 50%;
  background: lime;
}
#ul {
  top: 50%;
  background: red;
}
#ur {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="ol"></div>
<div id="or"></div>
<div id="ul"></div>
<div id="ur"></div>
```